# (AngularJS) ngClass is assigned with the correct string value but not updated on the view

Tags: angularjs, class

in HTML:

```
<td ><div class="ledborder"><div class="led" ng-class="GetLedClass('led1')"/></div></td>     
<td ><div class="ledborder"><div class="led" ng-class="GetLedClass('led2')"/></div></td> 
<td ><div class="ledborder"><div class="led" ng-class="GetLedClass('led3')"/></div></td> 
<td ><div class="ledborder"><div class="led" ng-class="GetLedClass('led4')"/></div></td> 
<td ><div class="ledborder"><div class="led" ng-class="GetLedClass('led5')"/></div></td>
```

in the controller:

```
var ledColorToBg = {'off':'dis_bg', 'red':'red_bg', 'green':'green_bg', 'orange':'orange_bg'};

$scope.GetLedClass = function(module){

    var retClass='';
    var color;

    if ($scope.ledsInfo == null){
        retClass = ledColorToBg['off'];
    }        
    else if ($scope.ledsInfo.systemError){
        retClass = 'red_bg blink';
    }
    else{        
        switch(module){
            case 'led1':
                color = $scope.ledsInfo.led1.led;
                break;

            case 'led2':
                color = $scope.ledsInfo.esxi.led2.led;
                break;

            case 'led3':
                color = $scope.ledsInfo.esxi.led3.led;
                break;

            case 'led4':
                color = $scope.ledsInfo.batteries.led4.led;
                break;

            case 'led5':
                color = $scope.ledsInfo.batteries.led5.led;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        retClass = ledColorToBg[color.color];

        if (color.blink)
            retClass += ' blink';
    }

    return retClass;
}
```

$scope.ledsInfo is updated every 4 seconds. In some cases (not 100% reproducible), $scope.GetLedClass returns the expected value, but the led class (reflected by the element color) is not updated on the view. When I inspect the HTML element, I see the correct/expected/updated class value, but it's not rendered on the view.

I know it's not an issue of syntax, because most of the times it's working.

I tried to put the function in $timeout, but it just made things worse: none of the elements updated.

I tried to put the function in $setTimeout, but it bahaved just as in $timeout.

I tried to keep 5 scope vars, updated when $scope.ledsInfo is updated, so ng-class would bind to these vars, as:

```
<td ><div class="ledborder"><div class="led" ng-class="{{ledClass.led1}}"/></div></td>     
<td ><div class="ledborder"><div class="led" ng-class="{{ledClass.led2}}"/></div></td> 
<td ><div class="ledborder"><div class="led" ng-class="{{ledClass.led3}}"/></div></td> 
<td ><div class="ledborder"><div class="led" ng-class="{{ledClass.led4}}"/></div></td> 
<td ><div class="ledborder"><div class="led" ng-class="{{ledClass.led5}}"/></div></td>
```

but it didn't work as well.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: try using $interval and after assigning value to color return it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna leave comments but my reputation is not enough yet. so..

how about try to use `$scope.$apply(function(){});` or `$digest`, or `$watch`

Comment: @S.Gillo can you post a plunker with this?